# AngularJS ng-show/ng-hide slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox

i am writing to you with small problem.

I have two sliders: sliderL and sliderC:
[image]

Sliders have directive ng-show="showSliderL" or ng-show="showSliderC".

functions:

[image]

it returns true or false (probably here i have problem).

And i have combobox with value: "rl" and "rc". 
How can I influence the value of combobox to affect the appearance and hiding of the sliders?

Here is my combobox choice function code:

[image]

Now both sliders are hidden.

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['rzModule']);

myApp.controller('TestController', TestController);

$scope.obwody = ['RL', 'RC'];
$scope.wybranyObwod = $scope.obwody[0];

 $scope.wybierzFunkcje = function () {
        var wybor = $scope.wybranyObwod;
        if (angular.equals('RL', wybor)) {
            $scope.sliderL.isHidden = false;
            $scope.sliderC.isHidden = true;
        } else if (angular.equals('RC', wybor)) {
            $scope.sliderC.isHidden = false;
            $scope.sliderL.isHidden = true;
        } else {
            console.log('idot');
        }
    }
    $scope.wybierzFunkcje();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jjye1cL/341/

Comment: you want to show only the selected slider in the dropdown is it

Comment: Why do you need the show functions? why not just do `ng-show="!sliderL.isHidden"` and then you can just set `$scope.sliderL.isHidden = true` if rc is selected and vice versa. PS next time please include your code as snippets instead of pictures, makes copying to test a massive pain.

Comment: Your clue doesn't work :(. Now i have 2 sliders show.

Comment: i added jsfiddle, if u can check